# Javascript - clearing duplicates from an array object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi
I have a javascript array object rapresenting the amount of items sold in a given country, like this:

```
var data = [{'c1':'USA', 'c2':'Item1', 'c3':100}, 
            {'c1':'Canada', 'c2':'Item1', 'c3':120},
            {'c1':'Italy', 'c2':'Item2', 'c3':140},
            {'c1':'Italy', 'c2':'Item2', 'c3':110}]
```

I need to avoid duplicates (as you may see, the last two 'records' have the same Country and the same Item) and sum the amounts; if I was getting data from a database I would use the DISTINCT SUM clause, but what about it in this scenario? Is there any good jquery trick?

Comment: Hm. The last two records do not really have the same item in your sample.

Comment: You could try to construct a new data structure (Object) (key = country name, value = rest of data). Check if key exists in the structure already while constructing the new one and sum accordingly. There might be a neater way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an object as a map of distinct values, like this:

```
var distincts, index, sum, entry, key;
distincts = {};
sum = 0;
for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
    entry = data[index];
    key = entry.c1 + "--sep--" + entry.c2;
    if (!distincts[key]) {
        distincts[key] = true;
        sum += entry.c3;
    }
}
```

**How that works**: JavaScript objects are maps, and since access to properties is an *extremely* common operation, a decent JavaScript implementation tries to make property access quite fast (by using hashing on property keys, that sort of thing). You can access object properties using a string for their name, by using brackets (`[]`), so `obj.foo` and `obj["foo"]` both refer to the `foo` property of `obj`.

And so:

1. We start with an object with no properties.
2. As we loop through the array, we create unique key from `c1` and `c2`. It's important that the "--sep--" string be something that *cannot* appear in `c1` or `c2`. If case isn't significant, you might throw a `.toLowerCase` in there.
3. If `distincts` already has a value for that key, we know we've seen it before and we can ignore it; otherwise, we add a value (`true` in this case, but it can be just about anything other than `false`, `undefined`, `0`, or `""`) as a flag indicating we've seen this unique combination before. And we add `c3` to the sum.

But as someone pointed out, your last two entries aren't actually the same; I'm guessing that was just a typo in the question...

Comment: @Tomalek: Took typing in high school. ;-)

Comment: It works. To be honest, I was expecting something a little less tricky than concatenating strings, but it's probably because of my ignorance about javascript. Thank you TJ.

Comment: @franz: Well, you could do a two-level deep thing, with the first level keyed by `c1` and the second level keyed by `c2`, but frankly it would make the code more complicated and wouldn't buy you anything at runtime. :-)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery may have an array function for this, but because your two Italy objects are not distinctly unique, your asking for a custom solution. You want to populate a array and check it for duplicates as you go:

```
var data = [{'c1':'USA', 'c2':'Item1', 'c3':100}, 
            {'c1':'Canada', 'c2':'Item1', 'c3':120},
            {'c1':'Italy', 'c2':'Item2', 'c3':140},
            {'c1':'Italy', 'c2':'Item1', 'c3':110}]

var newArray = [];
var dupeCheck = {}; // hash map
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
   if(!dupeCheck[data[i].c1]){
      newArray.push(data[i]);
      dupeCheck[data[i].c1] = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[test](http://jsfiddle.net/8H5sW/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
var data = [{'c1':'USA', 'c2':'Item1', 'c3':100}, 
            {'c1':'Canada', 'c2':'Item1', 'c3':120},
            {'c1':'Italy', 'c2':'Item2', 'c3':140},
            {'c1':'Italy', 'c2':'Item1', 'c3':110}];

var
 l = data.length, // length
 f = "",          // find
 ix = "",         // index
 d = [];          // delete    

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

   ix = data[i].c1 + "_" + data[i].c2 + "__";

   //var re = new RegExp(ix);

   //if (re.test(f))
   if (f.indexOf(ix) != -1)
     d.push(i);
   else
     f += ix;
}


for (var i1 = 0; i1 < d.length; i1++){

    $("#test").append("<div>for delete: "+d[i1]+"</div>");

}
```

**EDIT**

Although chrome works much faster, works only in chrome faster the example with indexOf, then in IE/Opera/Firefox/Safary works faster with an object.

The code created by "@ TJ Crowder" is much more efficient.

Comment: Er...and if the values in `c1` or `c2` have characters in them that are special in RegExps? (Think `*`, for instance.) Or `_` s? And...why the regexp, exactly? This is basically: Create one long string with keys (you don't need regexp for that) and then look to see if a key is already in the string.